# Guard for tuple of integers

Tags: erlang

I have a function that accepts coordinates (tuple) as one of its arguments:

```
func({X, Y}, Something) when is_integer(X), is_integer(Y) -> ...
```

I want to ensure that the coordinates:

- are tuple with 2 items (X and Y)
- both X and Y are integers

I can use the guard as above, and it works all right. But, I have many functions that use the coordinates and I wanted to know if I can clean up somehow this construct (some macro?) so would have something like:

```
func(XY, Something) when ?is_coord(XY) -> ... % how to define ?is_coord
```

Is there a clean and idiomatic way to do that? Is it erlang-ish?

**Edit**

[Erlang docs](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR11) explicitly discourage defensive programming:

> **3.13 Do not program "defensively"**
>
> A defensive program is one where the programmer does not "trust" the
> input data to the part of the system they are programming. In general
> one should not test input data to functions for correctness. Most of
> the code in the system should be written with the assumption that the
> input data to the function in question is correct. Only a small part
> of the code should actually perform any checking of the data. This is
> usually done when data "enters" the system for the first time, once
> data has been checked as it enters the system it should thereafter be
> assumed correct.

Comment: One disadvantage to taking any of the defensive programming approaches discussed here (other than niahoo's suggestion to use dialyzer) is that you're still stuck with the basic question: what to do if an invalid value is passed. If you just don't program defensively and let invalid values crash the process, that's typically the idiomatic approach.

Comment: @macintux: you're right, I added comment in the question for completeness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a clean and I think pretty Erlang-ish way to define `is_coord` macro:

```
-define(is_coord(C), tuple_size(C) =:= 2
                     andalso is_integer(element(1, C))
                     andalso is_integer(element(2, C))).

func(Coord, Something) when ?is_coord(Coord) ->
    ...
```

Note that [tuple_size/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#tuple_size-1) also implies [is_tuple/1](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_tuple-1) check.

Comment: The problem with the above is that if the variable is not tuple then it will throw an exception. Need to add is_tuple(C) andalso tuple_size(C)....

Comment: @vinod Guards don't throw exceptions. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80042 for details.

Answer (score 3):

hmmm well you can't exactly define your own guards, since the idea is to be completely sure that they don't have side effects (http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80042).

This quick hack works:

```
-define(GUARD(Name, Args), Name({X, Y}, Args) when is_integer(X), is_integer(Y)).
-export([myfun/2]).

?GUARD(myfun, [A, B, C]) ->
  io:format("hi~n"),
  ok.
```

Although i don't personally like it... Probably you could do a parse transform if you *really* need it: http://chlorophil.blogspot.com.ar/2007/04/erlang-macro-processor-v1-part-i.html, or preprocess your sources with a template engine, like mustache: https://github.com/mojombo/mustache.erl

hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Ning and marcelog's answers are both good and efficient, but personally i would either let the code as is or use one of them, and then :

1) define a type

```
-type point() :: {integer(),integer()}.
```

2) use Erlang's [dialyzer](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/dialyzer)

Comment: cool, just a note: the runtime check would be lost in this case, so a call with {undefined, whatever} would reach the function (guards would not be there)

Comment: That's why i said "keep the code as is" (with guards) or "use one of the both proposals", which both uses cases or guards) :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the parse transform library like [guardian](https://github.com/vinod-hg/guardian) and write the code something like below.

```
-compile({parse_transform, guardian}).

func(XY, Something) when is_coord(XY) ->
    do(Something);
func(XY, A) ->
    filering_out.

is_coord({X, Y}) when is_integer(X), is_integer(Y)->
   true;
is_coord(_) ->
   false.
```

The func function is transformed to the similar function as written by Ning's case statement function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case`:

```
-module(lab).

-compile(export_all).

go() ->
    func({1, 2}, "1st try"),
    func({a, 2}, "2nd try"),
    func({1, 2, 3}, "3rd try").

func(XY, Something) ->
    case is_coord(XY) of
        true -> io:format("~p~n", [Something]);
        false -> io:format("Not a coord~n")
    end.

is_coord(XY) ->
    case XY of
        {X, Y} when is_integer(X), is_integer(Y) ->
            true;
        _ ->
            false
    end.
```

Test run:

```
> c(lab), lab:go().
"1st try"
Not a coord
Not a coord
ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that we can have another solution.

We can define a `coord` record as:

```
-define(coord, {x = 0, y = 0}).
```

And then we can simply do:

```
func(XY, Something) when is_record(XY, coord) -> ...
```

We need to make sure we initialize `x` and `y` with integers when creating a `coord` record. (shouldn't be hard:))

***... both X and Y are integers*** [checked]

and `is_record(XY, coord)` guarantees the structure of `XY`.

***... are tuple with 2 items (X and Y)*** [checked]

Answer (score 1):

I would say record checking (is_record) cannot provide any guaranty that both elements are integers.. So, if you need to be sure you have 2 elements tuple with integeres, I'd use

```
 -define(is_coord(X), size(X)== 2 andalso is_integer(element(1,X)) andalso is_integer(element(2,X))).

 rr(X) when ?is_coord(X) -> coord;
 rr(_) -> not_coord.
```